# Tensorflow 2.0 - How to create a trainable variable that is the product of two matrices?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to create a dense layer, but instead of having XW = Y, I want to have X(WC)=Y, where W is a trainable weight and C is a constant variable of the same shape as W. I have tried creating my own custom Dense layer, but it seems that any time I multiply a trainable variable with a constant it is no longer treated as trainable. Appreciate any suggestions / advice!

My current approach:

```
class MaskedDense(Dense):
    #Dense layer defined here:
    #https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.0/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L1081-L1247
    def __init__(self, units, mask_weight, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MaskedDense, self).__init__(units, *args, **kwargs)        
        self.mask_weight = mask_weight
    
    
    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(MaskedDense, self).build(input_shape)
        self._underlying_kernel = self.kernel
        self.kernel_mask = tf.Variable(initial_value=self.mask_weight, trainable=False, name='kernelmask', dtype='float32')
        self._non_trainable_weights.append(self.kernel_mask)
        self.kernel = tf.math.multiply(self._underlying_kernel, self.kernel_mask)
```

Comment: please add your code

Comment: @Andrey added code!